# How to select parent and all children in same row

Tags: sql-server, database, parent-child

I have two tables,first consists list of customers and another table consists of products the customers have bought. I am trying to get the customer detail and the list of products bought in the same row. The number of columns of the table will be in accordance to the maximum number of item bought by a customer.

I have tried fetching users and product sales separately and while rendering i tried comparing the userid with sales userid. if the condition matched then it would be rendered in table.

```
select * from userTable;

select * from sales;
```

```
$.each(resp.userData, function(index, val) {
    table = table + ` <tr>
                   <td>${val.name}</td>
                   <td>${val.userId}</td>`
for (var i = 0; i < salesData.length; i++) {

     if(val.userId == salesData[i].userId){

        table = table + `<td> ${salesData[i].productName}</td>

                  <td>${salesData[i].productPrice}</td>`;
    }
 }
table = table + `</tr>`

});
```

The expected is somehow like:
`Name | UserID  | Product  | Price | Product | Price | Product | Price`

I think the expected output can be derived from the query instead of frontend rendering.

Comment: I highly recommend against having columns of the same name; your application is going to hate you if you do that. Sample data, expected result, and your attempts will be a great help here. What you are after is a "dynamic pivot" and there many examples of these on SO.

Comment: "I am trying to get the customer detail and the list of products bought in the same row."  Why? That's not a relational solution. I've never seen data reported that way, and even in Business Intelligence reporting for a reason- because such a format can't be aggregated to make sense of the data.  If someone buys 1000 products you minimally have a table 1000 columns wide.
 And what if someone buys more than one of the same item?

Comment: Actually its to create a report. The user and product is just a similar situation because full details cannot be listed out. Bt the report requires similar output. Talking about the number of columns in the given context, till now the user has only bought 17 products and may buy till 25-30products

Comment: Ask them to clarify the request and give a sample of expected output. It is possible you misunderstood the instructions. If they insist on that format, hope it is just for a few customers because there is no easy way to do that in pure SQL.  If it is for many customers- then you either have ignorant bosses or else they are giving you busy work to screw around with you.  Such data has no Business Intelligence value because you cannot aggregate it or determine trends (it's also really hard to read).